# Making constructor arguments privileged to ES6 class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ES5 I could use a factory pattern like this:

```
function factory(a) {
  return {
    say: function() {
      return console.log(a)
    }
  };
}

var instance = factory('hi');
instance.say(); // => 'hi'
instance.a; // => 'undefined'
```

The argument passed to the factory isn't set on the object it creates, so it is privileged to all the method definitions but isn't public to the author.

If I wanted to make this factory an ES6 class how can I reveal the constructor parameters in the same way?

```
let hack;

class Blah {
  constructor(a) {
    //bad!
    this.a = a;
    //but even worse?
    hack = a;
    //instance method is not a class method
    this.yell = () => console.log(a);
  }
  say() {
    console.log(hack);
  }
}

let blah = new Blah('hi');
blah.a; // => 'hi'
blah.hack; // => 'undefined'
blah.say(); // => 'hi'
blah.yell(); // => 'hi'
```

Comment: [This article](http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/private-data-classes.html) offers some choices, but I basically agree with deceze: you worry too much. :P For example, Python doesn't have private members at all; and it's chugging along just fine, just by using convention.

Comment: @Amadan Python is exactly what brought me to my view described below; the notion of *"we're all consenting adults here, just don't touch my privates m'kay"* is such an important lesson...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I wanted to make this factory an ES6 class how can I reveal the constructor parameters in the same way?

You can't. For the same reason you cannot make constructor arguments accessible to prototype methods: Scope.

Your factory method is just very different from what a class does. You can't use a class to achieve the same effect and that's OK. You don't *have to* use classes only because they exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.yell = () => console.log(a);
```

This is essentially what you're doing with your current factory as well. You're returning a new object with a specific instance method which closes over the particular instance-specific value. That's the only real way to make it work. If you want to use the prototype at all for methods, you ***need*** to use `this` to store the instance-specific value, otherwise there's no way for the method on `prototype` to get access to that value.

Having said all this, IMO, "private" values are extremely overrated, especially if you have to bend over backwards to make them happen. In the end they're only useful for human programmers to not accidentally "touch someone's privates" and mess up state. For that purpose a *naming convention* is often perfectly sufficient, e.g. `this.__my_private = a`. Just don't touch `__` variables, unless they're yours.

Comment: 100% ack. Embrace the language.